# Launching ROS on startup

Tags: ros, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have oneboard computer with Ubuntu server andI want to start my nodes after startup automatically. So I tried to to add
roslauch comand to rc.local and its not worked, than I find robot upstart package (http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstartand) and roscore starts automatically, but not my nodes. Can anyone help me with this problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279444/launching-ros-on-startup/) by [Amrello](https://answers.ros.org/users/31839/amrello/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-11**:
If you called robot_upstart on your Launch file, this should start. But all Launch files you want to start Need to be installed. If there is some HW-accesss from those nodes, another Problem could be that you don't have correct permissions for accessing the HW-ports (e.g. /dev/ttyUSB*)  with ...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-11**:
`Robot_upstart` and thus the node is crashing....

**Comment by [Amrello](https://answers.ros.org/users/31839/amrello/) on 2018-01-11**:
Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem. In my node I use serial communication with microcontroller so node can't open serial port and crushed.
In general here's what I did that I did:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and add

```
chmod 666 /dev/ttyS1
```

to change attributes, ttyS1 my serial port

---

Originally posted by [Amrello](https://answers.ros.org/users/31839/amrello/) with karma: 26 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0